# Can I send a mail on behalf of someone else using mail API?

Tags: email

Does the mail API (regardless of the programming language) allow to send mails on behalf of any arbitrary email address?

to understand what I mean, go here http://eyhosting.com/client_data/greatermedical/recform.php?item=comsu3397.html

And enter in the `*your email:` any arbitrary mail such as stevejobs@apple.com ... and in the `*email 1:` box enter your email .. Then watch your mail inbox.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is about. You say "the mail API", but it's not clear what exactly you're talking about. If you mean SMTP, then the answer is yes, it does. It's also not clear if you're talking about the envelope from or the body from. (For example, if I forward to you an email from Jeff to Jack, I am the envelope sender but Jeff is in the body from field.) Of course, each recipient is free to validate the sender (for example, using [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)) if it chooses to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes an email address specifies those to, from, attachments, etc fields in the header.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal mail API.  But yes, it is possible (and even easy) to send mail and spoof the sender's address, for legitimate and less-than-legitimate reasons.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP is the email protocol.  See [RFC 821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc821.txt), [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt), [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), and [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt). While depending on the version of the protocol, the syntax changes slightly, the receiving server always trusts the from address that the sending client specifies.  While there are other protocols which do perform sender identification and header overwriting, such as Exchange, these are in the minority.